# How to port legacy UMDF HID driver to UWD

Tags: windows, driver, hid, universal, umdf

I am working on making the legacy HID driver written using UMDF UWD compliant.
I have gone through the MSDN documentation on writing the universal windows drivers and did not see any article on  porting the existing legacy drivers to UWD.

Can someone help with the documentation on this ? or the approach to be taken ?